# How to print a Single face (one sided) 3D scan

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I took a scan using Polycam on my phone of a 3D object and exported it, but when put it in Cura it says there are missing surfaces, and I’m pretty sure this is because it’s only taken face-on, there is no back. When I go to print preview it looks strange and doesn’t work, I just want to print the scan I have taken attached to a block or something.

I am happy to provide images, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you've created a 3D scan, the resulting mesh will have depth, perhaps not a great depth. The slicer dislikes open mesh and as you've discovered, will not print in a manner to meet your requirements.

Using a third party program to adjust the mesh into a 2D image, you can then extrude the necessary depth to create a manifold 3D print. Without knowing your comfort level with other software, it can be a challenge to determine the best program.

First to mind is Meshmixer (free, multi-platform), Fusion 360 (free hobbyist version), OpenSCAD, (free, multi-platform) and many others with which I'm not as familiar.

One would import the recently created mesh, clean up the debris typically created by these scanner programs and if possible, extrude within the selected program to create the depth aspect.

As an example, one can import the mesh file into Fusion 360, create a sketch plane and project the mesh onto the plane. This creates the 2D image which can be extruded within Fusion 360 to create a printable, exportable file.

The real key here is to implement just one more program to take that step to your goal.

Comment: Thanks so much - funnily in the time between posting the question and receiving this answer I went off and researched and have ended up fixing it using Meshmixer, but this still helps me understand why so I appreciate your post regardless.

Comment: @Dash - If this answered your issue (whether directly or indirectly) consider selecting the checkmark below the voting arrows to show it's good to go.